# Change Text Color of Label in cell with if statement

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to change the color of a label (or labels) in a cell if the value of alarmLevel != "0".  This is what I have so far and it's changing the color of the cell.locationLabel in all of the cells instead of just the ones that satisfy the if statement.  I'm sure its something to do with the indexPath but I cant figure it out.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
    cell.locationLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].location
    cell.eventTimeLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].dateTime
    cell.eventTypeLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyEventSubtypeCode
    cell.agencyIdLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyId

    if alarmLevel != "0" {
      cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    } else {
      cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem to make us help you

Comment: I want the labels of ONLY the cell that’s alarm level != 0 to be red. The above code turns the labels in all of the cells red which is what I DONT want.

Comment: You seem to be using the same `alarmLevel` value for every execution of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. You might want to use the appropriate value, similar as you did for the other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `alarmLevel` as an integer variable to the events list array type. And change this integer value according to your need for each `event` item in the array `eventsList`

```
class Events {
    var location = String()
    var dateTime = String()
    var agencyEventSubtypeCode = Int()
    var agencyId = Int()
    var alarmLevel = Int() //Need this here
}

var eventsList = [Events]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
cell.locationLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].location
cell.eventTimeLabel.text = eventsList[indexPath.row].dateTime
cell.eventTypeLabel.text = ("\(eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyEventSubtypeCode)")
cell.agencyIdLabel.text = ("\(eventsList[indexPath.row].agencyId)")

if eventsList[indexPath.row].alarmLevel != 0 {
  cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
} else {
  cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
}
return cell
}
```

Comment: I have a class Events that I have the alarmLevel variable in.  It actually comes in as a String.  I changed my if statement to:                                                     if eventsList[indexPath.row].alarmLevel != "0" {
  cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
} else {
  cell.locationLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
}  ........ but now it doesnt change color at all.

Comment: No problem a class or a struct it is the same thing Just that the class you can inherit from and the struct no. You said that alarmLevel is a string value in your class i will change the code to suit your need but i prefer that you use integer specially that it will always be a number and no characters would be included in. Then you will have to just get the alarmLevel value while looping on your array eventsLists.

Comment: print out the alarmLevel value on your console while looping and make sure the value is being changed. Because if the value is the same in every item in your eventsList array then the text color wont change of course.